# Porcentagem de chance de cair X valor ao usar Math.random() num array

Tags: javascript, array, random

Como posso fazer para ter, por exemplo, 90% de chance de cair 2 e 10% de chance de cair 1?

```
var array = [2, 1];
var result = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Supondo que x vá de 0 a 99 vindo de outra parte do código, `var resultado = x < 10 ? 1 : 2`. Mas em JS o random ja é de 0 até "menos que um", então não precisa nada de "por cento" (matemática básica é indispensável para programar), basta fazer direto um `var resultado = Math.random() < .1 ? 1 : 2`. - Se não entende o que é o `?`, ele está no lugar do if. Dá no mesmo que `var resultado; if (Math.random()<.1) {resultado = 1;} else {resultado = 2;}`, não precisa de soluções "Rube Goldberg".

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução seria tu construires o array com essa proporção. No caso 90-10, ficaria assim:

```
var array = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1];
var result = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Pensei nessa possibilidade também, mas não há outro meio?